# Nodejs express server not closing

Tags: node.js, express, server

I have an express nodejs server with express-generator. After calling "npm start" server starts properly but I'm not able to close the connection to localhost. Typical exiting the process with "ctrl+c" doesn't work as expected. After "ctrl+c" I'm not able to start the server on the same localhost port again. I'm still using Win7, my node is up to date and other globally installed packages. **My console prints out following:**

```
$ npm start

> myapp@0.0.0 start C:\Users\Konrad\dev\myapp
> node ./bin/www

Port 3000 is already in use
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Konrad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-19T20_02_46_983Z-debug.log
```

**Thats the code in bin/www:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I use an automatically generated template from express-generator. I can update the post and show the app.js file if needed.

Comment: You can look for `SIGINT` in your code. If you find it you can add the relevant part to your question. When you use Ctrl-C in a cmd window in Windows it sends a SIGINT signal. If you "hijack" this event (which is normal) and don't do process.exit()  afterward you can end up with Ctrl-C not exiting the application.

Comment: I haven't found "SIGINT" anywhere.  So I can add a script to listen for "SIGINT" and then execute "process.exit()"?

Comment: If you didn't find that mentioned anywhere then that shouldn't be the problem. You can disregard what I said.

Comment: Looks like `ctrl+c` doesn't end your process. Are you using standard windows console? People report this issue when using non-standard consoles (e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16103).

Comment: You are correct. I wasn't using the standard cmd line. I just wanted to try out the standard console but now I cannot run "npm start". It directs me to the right dir and runs node (node ./bin/www, this is the dir where my serv config is) but it does not go any further. What may be the issue? I'm starting to dislike windows, never had those issues with macOS.

Answer (score 0):

So, to avoid this issue I started using the package called "nodemon". It refreshes the code of my application without the need to restart the server.

The issue remains unsolved but I hope nobody else encounters this problem. It was probably my mistake combined with some windows7 incompatibility.